# Flask -- Use a button to submit text in a text box (a form)

Tags: flask

I'm currently using Flask and I want to have a "Submit" button that will POST the data in a form to Python once the button is pushed.

MY text box looks like this:

```
<form method="POST"> <style> 
textarea {
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
padding: 12px 20px;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid #ccc;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: #f8f8f8;
font-size: 16px;
resize: none;
}
</style>
```

My button looks like this:

```
<button type="submit"></button>
```

My run.py looks like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def some_function():
    // do stuff
```

EDIT: I can't get the POST method to work. The button appears, and even when it is pressed, it does nothing.

Comment: what issue are you facing exactly ?

Comment: Oops, sorry. Edited -- I can't get the POST method to work. The butotn appears but it does nothing when pressed.

Comment: Did you place the button inside the form ? otherwise could you post the whole form, at least the relevant part

Comment: should the button go inside the form? edit: ill try it

Comment: It worked, but now text=request.form["text"] is giving me "Bad Request." How should I be expressing that?

Comment: i had luck guessing the button place, but i really need more code to help you here, check the name of the textarea is all i can tell

Comment: You're right, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have your answer, but to others who will read this question later, and because you have so many mistakes in your pasted code that isn't going to make it any usable for others:

you should place the `button` inside the form, so your form would look like this:

```html
<style> 
  textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  font-size: 16px;
  resize: none;
  }
</style>
<form method="POST"> 
  <textarea name="textbox"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

so you have a `textarea` and a `button` to send the form.

now, in your `run.py`:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["POST"])
def some_function():
    text = request.form.get('textbox')
```

now, you can do whatever you like to text.